# Is angular/http at angular2.js or http.js?

Tags: angular

This is a stupid question but I just don't see a concrete answer elsewhere.

I am using `angular2@^2.0.0-beta.0` installed with npm. In the `node_modules/angular2/bundles/` folder, if I want to use the `Http` service, should I include the `angular2.js` with `http.js` or just `angular2.js` alone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use the `Http` class in Angular2, you need to include the `http.dev.js` file:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
```

You need to specify `HTTP_PROVIDERS` when bootstrapping your main component to maker it available in dependency injection:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/http';
(...)

bootstrap(MainComponent, [ HTTP_PROVIDERS ]);
```

You can then inject it within a component or a service as described below:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'first-app',
  template: `
    (...)
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(http:Http) {
    this.http = http;
  }

  executeHttpRequest() {
    this.http.get('https://angular2.apispark.net/v1/companies/')
             .map(res => res.json())
             .subscribe({
                data => this.companies = data });
  }
}
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should include `http.js` or `http.dev.js` or `http.min.js` in addition to angular 2 core.